# How can I remove an empty space in php output?

Tags: php

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" class="status" value="
    <?php if (!empty ($status)) {
        echo $status;
    } else {
        echo "default";
    } ?>" 
    />
```

My result is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" class="status" value=" default">
```

My problem is: There is an empty space in `value=" default"`

And I cannot remove it. I cannot see, why it is there...

Comment: spaces before the php tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breaks are validated as a space if in HTML scope. So you could, for example, place the opening PHP tag directly after `value="`. Anyway, let me make this suggestion to improve your code:

```
<input (...) value="<?php echo !empty($status) ? $status : 'default'; ?>">
```

[Shorthand if statements](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php) are pretty useful for these cases because they are compact and are, if you get used to them, very readable.

Please note, that since HTML5 you don't need the self-escaping (`/>`) for tags that are marked as self-closing. the `input` tag is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" class="status" value="
    <?php if (!empty ($status)) {
        echo $status;
    } else {
        echo "default";
    } ?>" 
    />
```

To:

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" class="status" value="<?php if (!empty ($status)) {
    echo $status;
} else {
    echo "default";
} ?>" 
/>
```